# Proof for $log\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\right)$ diverging.

Tags: calculus

Proof for $log\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\right)$ diverging. I know that the harmonic series diverges. What is the quickest way to prove the logarithm of it diverges?

I have not used any logarithms in proving the harmonic series diverges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\log \left(\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n}\right) > C \Leftrightarrow \left(\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n}\right) > e^C$$

Comment: Would it be ok to replace the m with infinity?

Comment: @Tim: To what end?  Recall that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \infty$ is shorthand for the following statement: For any value $C > 0$, there exists an $m$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^m a_n > C$.  N.S.'s hint falls right into such a definition.  You can prove such an $m$ exists for the "logarithmized" series for any $C$, by using the $m$ you get for the "unlogarithmized" series for $e^C$.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a proof that $\log (\infty) = \infty.$ What is your definition of $\log (\infty)?$ As soon as that is made precise, your answer should follow readily.

Comment: First +1.  Second, perhaps the OP was thinking of the Cauchy Principal Value $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\zeta (1+\epsilon)+\zeta (1-\epsilon)}{2}=\gamma"="\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$$in which case it isn't $\log(\infty)$ it's simply $\log(\gamma)$ ... ;-))))))))  - Mark